# System identification of Blue Robotics Thruster with Simscape multibody

Tags: dynamics, modeling, simulation, simulink, system-identification

I have CAD design of a Blue Robotics Thruster 200.
The thruster is imported to Simulink.

From data given Blue Robotics Thruster 200 have MATLAB system identification toolbox been used
to generate thruster dynamics. The output is a thruster force given a input.

A link to the use of system identification with Matlab to identify a transfer function model is given below.
[Tutorial system identification Blue Robotics thruster](https://se.mathworks.com/videos/matlab-and-simulink-robotics-arena-from-data-to-model-1518156121608.html)
and one more link for the thruster model.
[Blue robotics thruster tutorial](https://bluerobotics.com/learn/thruster-usage-guide/)

I have then imported the transfer function from system identification to Simulink see picture below.

[image]

So my question is should input settings on the revolute joint be a torque or a motion?